# server restrict outbound traffic, can I still use c# WebClient?

Tags: webclient

I'm confused about this object WebClient in asp.net. If I use this object to call an endpoint and my server has a restriction on any outbound traffic, will this still work?

Comment: This is quite vague. What kind of restrictions? Can you access it otherwise? Why do you think WebClient would work somehow uniquely?

Comment: thank you for the quick response Sami.

Comment: thank you for the quick response Sami. If my server firewall blocks internet traffic will WebClient still work?

Comment: I guess in essence... when I use WebClient in asp.net, am I using the client's browser to fetch data? I know this is such a novice question but I can't seem to find any resources that explains this.

Comment: or webClient uses system.net to replicate as a fake browser?

Comment: It connects to the server and requests data in the same way as any other system doing HTTP requests. If the server allows it it works. If it doesn’t it won’t work. WebClient doesn’t do anything special in that sense